# How to convert the RadioGroup element's ID into a string in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

The code below shows the id of RadioButton in toast and also as a name in button but I want to convert into string.

```
  radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    radioGroup.clearCheck();

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if (null != rb && checkedId > -1) {

                Toast.makeText(activity.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           p1_button.setText(rb.getText());


            }

        }
    });
```

I want to get the value of radio button as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy,
if you want to convert the value to string you can use `toString()` method like this

```
rb.getText().toString();
```

And also you can use `String.valueOf()` method like this

```
String.valueOf(rb.getText);
```

So in your case

```
 p1_button.setText(rb.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

well actually rb.getText() returns a string. 
you can assign its value to a string variable like

`String str=rb.getText();`

To be on the safer side:

`String str=""+rb.getText();`

in the above line the value from rb.getText() is concatenated with "" (+ is used to concatenate strings). using ""+ converts any value on the RHS of the + into string

or

`String str=rb.getText().toString();`

now 'str' contains the string value you are asking for